How to customize voice instructions on flutter_mapbox_navigation^0.2.2?
I am using the latest verstion of the plugin (0.2.2) also.
And if I set voiceInstructionsEnabled: false, the app is shut down unexpectly.
But the app runs flexible if voiceInstructionsEnable: true.
So I cannot customize voiceInstruction.
How can I resolve this?
Or when customized sound is played, can I mute the voice instruction?
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): Process: com.example.untitled, PID: 27278
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /directions/v5/mapbox/driving/-6.58909461927%2C53.3826809636;-6.587864%2C53.388655;-6.589743%2C53.387647;-6.599891%2C53.389552;-6.599701%2C53.389442;-6.59922%2C53.390455;-6.590373%2C53.382565?access_token=pk***********************************************************************************************&alternatives=true&avoid_maneuver_radius=18.031&bearings=151.365%2C45%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B&continue_straight=true&enable_refresh=true&geometries=polyline6&layers=0%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B&routes_history=KPXGmPFtKwnbI6HMo6FRbRxdivKvP0ZHiDyopIeIl77o0tgPRT9r1A%3D%3D_us-west-2%2C0%2C0&steps=true&waypoint_names=%3BLyreen%20Lawn%3BLyreen%20Drive%3BMoyglare%20Village%3BMoyglare%20Village%3BMoyglare%20Abbey%3BCross%20Lane&waypoints=0%3B1%3B2%3B3%3B4%3B5%3B6
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at java.net.URL.(URL.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at java.net.URL.(URL.java:498)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at java.net.URL.(URL.java:447)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at com.mapbox.navigation.base.route.NavigationRouteEx.toNavigationRoute(NavigationRoute.kt:588)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at com.mapbox.navigation.base.internal.route.NavigationRouteEx.toNavigationRoute(NavigationRouteEx.kt:244)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at com.mapbox.navigation.base.internal.utils.DirectionsResponseUtilsKt.parseRouteInterface(DirectionsResponseUtils.kt:59)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at com.mapbox.navigation.base.internal.utils.DirectionsResponseUtilsKt.parseNativeDirectionsAlternative(DirectionsResponseUtils.kt:51)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at com.mapbox.navigation.core.routealternatives.RouteAlternativesController$processRouteAlternatives$1$alternatives$1$expected$1.invokeSuspend(RouteAlternativesController.kt:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
E/AndroidRuntime(27278): Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@eec93ae, Dispatchers.Main]
I/Process (27278): Sending signal. PID: 27278 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:irrish_driving/widgets/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mapbox_navigation/flutter_mapbox_navigation.dart';
import 'package:irrish_driving/models/route.dart';

class LocationPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const LocationPicker({Key? key, required this.route}) : super(key: key);
  final TestRoute route;

  @override
  State<LocationPicker> createState() => _SampleNavigationAppState();
}


class _SampleNavigationAppState extends State<LocationPicker> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  String? _platformVersion;
  String? _instruction;
  bool isWaypointInstructionGiven = false;

  var wayPoints = <WayPoint>[];
  bool _isMultipleStop = false;
  double? _distanceRemaining, _durationRemaining;
  MapBoxNavigationViewController? _controller;
  bool _routeBuilt = false;
  bool _isNavigating = false;
  bool _inFreeDrive = false;
  bool _voiceInstruction = true;
  var voiceStr = <String>[];
  var curStep = 0;
  late MapBoxOptions _navigationOption;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initialize() async {
    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    _navigationOption = MapBoxNavigation.instance.getDefaultOptions();
    _navigationOption.language = "en";
    MapBoxNavigation.instance.registerRouteEventListener(_onEmbeddedRouteEvent);
    int startPoints = widget.route.start_points;
    for (var i = 0, cnt = 0; i < widget.route.m_points.length; i++) {
      if(i>0&&i<startPoints) continue;
         wayPoints.add(WayPoint(
            name: String.fromCharCode(i + 'A'.codeUnitAt(0)),
            latitude: widget.route.m_points[i].langtitude,
            longitude: widget.route.m_points[i].longtitude,
            isSilent: false));
         voiceStr.add(widget.route.m_points[i].action);
         for (var j = 0 ; j < widget.route.m_points[i].m_relays.length ; j ++ ) {
           wayPoints.add(WayPoint(
               name: "corner",
               latitude: widget.route.m_points[i].m_relays[j].langtitude,
               longitude: widget.route.m_points[i].m_relays[j].longtitude,
               isSilent: false));
           voiceStr.add(widget.route.m_points[i].m_relays[j].action);
         }
    }
    print(voiceStr);
    String? platformVersion;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      platformVersion = await MapBoxNavigation.instance.getPlatformVersion();
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    //start navigation
    _isMultipleStop = true;
    MapBoxNavigation.instance.startNavigation(
        wayPoints: wayPoints,
        options: MapBoxOptions(
            mode: MapBoxNavigationMode.driving,
            tilt: 45.0,
            language: "en",
            allowsUTurnAtWayPoints: true,
            units: VoiceUnits.metric,
            alternatives: false,
            simulateRoute: true,
            mapStyleUrlDay: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12",
            mapStyleUrlNight: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-night-v1"));

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }

  void playAudio(String message) async {
    print(message);
    String audioUrl = actions[message]!['audio'];
    print("************************************************************ ${audioUrl}");
    await player.play(UrlSource(audioUrl));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Irish Driving test App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: MapBoxNavigationView(
                    options: _navigationOption,
                    onRouteEvent: _onEmbeddedRouteEvent,
                    onCreated:
                        (MapBoxNavigationViewController controller) async {
                      _controller = controller;
                      controller.initialize();
                    }),
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onEmbeddedRouteEvent(e) async {
    _distanceRemaining = await MapBoxNavigation.instance.getDistanceRemaining();
    _durationRemaining = await MapBoxNavigation.instance.getDurationRemaining();
    print(e.eventType);
    switch (e.eventType) {
      case MapBoxEvent.progress_change:
        var progressEvent = e.data as RouteProgressEvent;
        var distanceToNextWaypoint = progressEvent.currentLegDistanceRemaining;
        print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ${distanceToNextWaypoint} ${isWaypointInstructionGiven}');

        if (progressEvent.currentStepInstruction != null) {
          _instruction = progressEvent.currentStepInstruction;
        }

        if (progressEvent.legIndex != curStep) {
          curStep = progressEvent.legIndex!;
          isWaypointInstructionGiven = false;
        }

        // Custom instruction logic
        if (distanceToNextWaypoint != null && distanceToNextWaypoint < 100 && !isWaypointInstructionGiven) {
          print("${progressEvent.legIndex}, ${progressEvent.stepIndex}");
          playAudio(voiceStr[progressEvent.legIndex!]);
          isWaypointInstructionGiven = true;
        } else if (distanceToNextWaypoint != null && distanceToNextWaypoint >= 100) {
          isWaypointInstructionGiven = false;
        }
        break;
      case MapBoxEvent.route_building:
      case MapBoxEvent.route_built:
        setState(() {
          _routeBuilt = true;
        });
        break;
      case MapBoxEvent.speech_announcement:
        setState(() {
          _voiceInstruction = false;
        });
      case MapBoxEvent.route_build_failed:
        setState(() {
          _routeBuilt = false;
        });
        break;
      case MapBoxEvent.navigation_running:
        setState(() {
          _isNavigating = true;
        });
        break;
      case MapBoxEvent.on_arrival:
        if (!_isMultipleStop) {
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
          await _controller?.finishNavigation();
        } else {}
        break;
      case MapBoxEvent.navigation_finished:
      case MapBoxEvent.navigation_cancelled:
        setState(() {
          _routeBuilt = false;
          _isNavigating = false;
        });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}

I added customized voice instruction on this app but I believe the voice instructions of app and the sound of customized sound are merged and coincidentally sound alike.
